# date.timezone issue in php.ini

Tags: php, iis

I trying to installing php on IIS based on [these steps](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-on-iis/install-and-configure-php).

I fallowed the instructions step by step and I did every thing correct, after all when i trying to see my phpinfo() i got this error:

> PHP Warning:  phpinfo(): It is not safe to rely on the system's
>   timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting
>   or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of
>   those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely
>   misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for
>   now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone.

So I came back to my php.ini and set date.timezone like this and restart the IIS:

```
;date.timezone = "America/New_York"
```

but nothing happened and same as the old.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove comment symbol `;` and restart IIS